# Azure Table Property/Column list

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have an a table Azure Table Storage where the various rows have a completely different set of properties.

Is there an existing method to query the table so that I can get a list of all the property/column names or do I just have to pull back the all the rows and parse it myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to get the list short of retrieving all the entities (rows).

Comment: That's what I though.  I figured if there was something it would save me time.  It would explain why searching found nothing.

Thanks.

apk